# Extending HTTP module in Angular2 throws error

Tags: http, angular, typescript

I am trying to extend the Angular2 HTTP module in order to create an HTTP interceptor of sorts.. the only problem is when I try to extend this module I get the following error:

```
No provider for ConnectionBackend!
```

I have no idea why this is happening and can't seem to get this error to go.

Here is my custom HTTP module:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {
    constructor(
        backend: ConnectionBackend,
        defaultOptions: RequestOptions
    ) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        console.log('request...');
        return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
            // do something
        });
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        console.log('get...');
        return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
            // do something
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my app.module.ts file:

```
import 'app/rxjs-extensions';

import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

import { AuthGuard } from "./guards/auth.guard";
import { routing } from "./app.routing";

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

import { HomeComponent } from "./components/home/HomeComponent";
import { LoginComponent } from "./components/login/LoginComponent";
import { NavBarComponent } from "./components/navbar/NavBarComponent";
import { ProductComponent } from "./components/catalog/products/ProductComponent";

import { GlobalEventsManager } from "./services/globalEventsManager.service";
import { AuthService } from "./services/auth.service";
import { ToastModule } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';
import { LeftNavComponent } from "./components/left-nav/left-nav-component";
import { SettingsComponent } from "./components/settings/settings-component";
import { UsersComponent } from "./components/users/users-component";
import { OptionsComponent } from "./components/catalog/options/OptionsComponent";
import { CategoriesComponent } from "./components/catalog/categories/CategoriesComponent";
import { ManufacturersComponent } from "./components/catalog/manufacturers/ManufacturersComponent";
import { ProductSearchComponent } from "./components/catalog/products/directives/ProductSearchComponent";
import { ProductListComponent } from "./components/catalog/products/directives/ProductListComponent";
import { ProductService } from "./services/product.service";
import { HttpInterceptor } from "./services/HttpInterceptor.service";


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        routing,
        ToastModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        NavBarComponent,
        ProductComponent,
        ProductSearchComponent,
        ProductListComponent,
        LeftNavComponent,
        SettingsComponent,
        UsersComponent,
        OptionsComponent,
        CategoriesComponent,
        ManufacturersComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
        AuthGuard,
        GlobalEventsManager,
        ProductService,
        HttpInterceptor
    ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

I have tried placing the my HttpInterceptor module inside the providers array in this file and this still doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to construct and provide your extended class yourself like so:

```
    ProductService,
    {
        provide: HttpInterceptor,
        useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) =>
            new HttpInterceptor(backend, defaultOptions),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }
],
```

Comment: This does not work unfortunately.. I get a 'xhrBackend is not defined' error

Comment: Yeah just realised that just as you posted your updated answer! works great cheers!

Comment: what about injecting another "MyService" in there ? I add it in the provide declaration and also in the `HttpInterceptor` constructor and got `No provider for MyService`

Comment: Using `XHRBackend` works fine on browser platform, but it has some issues in server platform. For me, routing doesn't work fine when using the extended http client in resolve guards.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to inject another MyService in there, you can do

```
   {
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, MyService],
      provide: HttpInterceptor,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, myService: MyService) =>
        new HttpInterceptor(backend, defaultOptions, myService),
    },
```

After that, just inject `MyService` in the `HttpInterceptor`